# How do I create a widget code for anything on a site so that I can embed it on another site?

Tags: html, css, widget, embed, devtools

We already have a search widget but I want to create a different widget. I want to create a widget of this book carousel from https://accessmedicine.mhmedical.com/ (this is just a screenshot):

[image]

I want to create this widget so that I can embed it on other sites (learning management system). How do I do this?

Do I use DevTools and Page Source? The code that I copy over to test does not replicate the carousel. It just shows a list of books.

I could only capture the HTML of the books and not the carousel with the arrows. It only showed up vertically and not how it looks on the site.

[image]

I also tried to copy this data from Chrome DevTools, but that didn't work:
[image]

Because only the previous and next buttons showed up:
[image]

How do I copy the code for the entire carousel (how it looks and its functions, features, links, etc.) so I can use it as a widget code and be able to embed it elsewhere?

Comment: You might be looking for [iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Comment: @asyncawait Thank you, but I don't see an https for the carousel of books, only the link sources for the individual books.

Comment: I was thinking you'd make the carousel it's own page, then just iframe it into whatever page you want it to be on. Of course html template engines would be better, but might expand your stack a bit. Maybe I'm misunderstanding some of what you want to accomplish. Do you have access to source code or redeploying the carousel?

Comment: @asyncawait I wish I could make the carousel its own page but I don't know how to do that. I'm not familiar with html template engines, and I only know the source code in "View page source" when you right click with Windows in Chrome.